# Facing issues with userinput as dplyr filter criteria to create dynamic Rshiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a simple bar plot in a shiny app with `covid_df <- covid19.data("aggregated")` data.

Taking **user input for filtering countries** to plot relevant states on x axis and another **user input to select type of cases like - Confirmed, Active, Deaths etc**.

#### Issues

In the **Bar Chart I get all the bars(states cases) of same height** irrespective of country or case type I choose (P.S - Attached Image) - How do I resolve this issue ? It seems to be small but I am unable to fix.

[image]

#### DataFrame

```
dim(covid_df)
[1] 3940   12

head(covid_df)

Province_State Country_Region         Last_Update      Lat      Long_ Confirmed Deaths Recovered ..
1 South Carolina             US 2020-08-09 04:34:54 34.22333  -82.46171       325      8         0
2      Louisiana             US 2020-08-09 04:34:54 30.29506  -92.41420      2570     79         0
3       Virginia             US 2020-08-09 04:34:54 37.76707  -75.63235      1095     16         0
```

#### UI

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    titlePanel("Covid Data"),
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("inCountry", "Select a Country for Statewise Barchart", 
                        choices = covid_df$Country_Region),
            
            selectInput("inCaseType", "Select Cases Type for Statewise Barchart", 
                        choices = names(covid_df[,c(6:9)])),
            
            textInput("plot_title", "Insert Plot title"),
            textInput("xlabel", "Insert X axis label"), 
            textInput("ylabel", "Insert Y axis label")                
        ),            
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("covidPlot")
        )
    )
)
```

#### Server

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
    
    output$covidPlot <- renderPlot({
        
        covid_df %>%
            filter(Country_Region == input$inCountry) %>% 
            select(Province_State, input$inCaseType) %>% 
            ggplot() +
            geom_bar(aes(x = Province_State, y = input$inCaseType), stat = "identity") +
            labs(xlab = input$xlabel, ylab = input$ylabel, main = input$plot_title)                
    })        
})

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**This same code of data filtering & plotting works when I hard code country name and case type instead of user input.**

I think there is some issue with `input$inCaseType` but I am not sure and this question may look stupid to others but I am asking this question as I am new to R & shiny and not able to solve by browsing other pages as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input$inCaseType` is string, so either we convert to `sym`bol in `aes` and evaluate (`!!`) or use the deprecated `aes_string`

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){

output$covidPlot <- renderPlot({
    
    covid_df %>%
         filter(Country_Region == input$inCountry) %>% 
         select(Province_State, input$inCaseType) %>% 
         ggplot() +
            geom_bar(aes(x = Province_State,
           y = !! rlang::sym(input$inCaseType)), stat = "identity") + 
         labs(xlab = input$xlabel, ylab = input$ylabel, main = input$plot_title)                
     })        
 })
```

NOTE: Instead of `names(covid_df[,c(6:9)])`, it may be better `names(covid_df)[6:9]`

Also, we may need the `unique` values of 'Country_Region' as `choices`

```
selectInput("inCountry", "Select a Country for Statewise Barchart", 
                    choices = unique(covid_df$Country_Region))
```

Comment: thanks @akrun this worked and this is the second time you helped me !! And I actually thought of this and tried as.numeric(input$inCaseType) before posting but that didn't work. I guess I still have alot to learn in R. Thanks again !